# Queue Exec Time

Tags: tasks, stalled-tasks

Please see the attached screenshot. On heavy tasks the queue is cancelled. Where do I set the timeout or remove it completely?
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you push the job to the queue you can specify the `ttr` (time to reserve) in order to prevent the job being cancelled after 300 seconds (the default).

```
Craft::$app->queue->ttr(3600);
Craft::$app->queue->push($myJob);
```

Alternatively, you can make your Job class implement `RetryableJobInterface` and then give it its own `getTtr()` method. 
See the [docs that explain this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/retryable.md#retryablejobinterface).

```
class SomeJob extends \craft\queue\BaseJob implements RetryableJobInterface
{
    public function getTtr()
    {
        return 3600;
    }
}
```

Or via configuration `config/app.php`:

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'queue' => [
            'ttr' => 600,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Finally, you can also achieve this using the provided [event handlers](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/retryable.md#event-handlers).

Comment: Thank you. I think Brandon's method here is slightly cleaner: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3147#issuecomment-407475927

Comment: Agreed, I've updated the answer to match.